# Any way to target a CSS class using a # character?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to target a class containing the # character?

We use an HTML-based writing platform for our documentation. Recently, they changed a CSS class applied to  tags to apply a backgroud-color. While the example below is to apply a light-yellow 35% background-color, they have done a similar conversion from color name to color number for all background-colors.

Old:
`<td  class="highlight-yellow confluenceTd">`

New:
`<td  class="highlight-#fffae6 confluenceTd">`

Here is the CSS we use to target the class:

Old:

```
.wiki-content td.highlight-yellow,
.wiki-content td.highlight-yellow > p,
.wiki-content tbody tr td.highlight-yellow,
.wiki-content tbody tr td.highlight-yellow > p {
    background-color: #FFFFDD;
}
```

New:

```
.wiki-content td.highlight-#fffae6,
.wiki-content td.highlight-#fffae6 > p,
.wiki-content tbody tr td.highlight-#fffae6,
.wiki-content tbody tr td.highlight-#fffae6 > p {
    background-color: #FFFAE6;
}
```

As you can see, they used the # character in the class name. To my knowledge the # character is not recognized in CSS class names and will be ignored. As expected, when I tried to target this class name with CSS, it fails. All tables using a class with the # character are rendered with no background-color applied.

Thanks.

Comment: Simply escape it: `.highlight-\#fffae6`.

Comment: Thank you - hadn't seen that before. Obviously I'm not an expert - appreciate the help.